# Suppress Alerts in android application

Tags: android

Is there any way to suppress all alerts in an android application.
I want to suppress all alerts that appear in my application eventhough it is created by me or it is coming from any other library. Is it possible in android.

Comment: What do you consider to be an "alert"?

Comment: By Alert, I mean AlertDialogs and Dialogs

Comment: As far as I know .. you can't do it for third party apps

Comment: what if I am using a third party library? Did u mean that?

Answer (score 0):

You are welcome to "suppress all alerts" in any source code you have access to, by simply not showing any such "alerts" in the first place.

If a third-party binary-only library displays "alerts" and does not give you the ability to block them, do not use that library.